# Unable to launch firefox browser and run test with RSpec in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec, rubymine

I am new to Ruby and Rspec. I just did below steps.

- Clicked on New Project in RubyMine
- Gave title as Selenium2(just some random name)
- I am using ruby 2.7.1
- Created a new directory 'src' under Selenium2 folder
- Added test.rb file
- I added below code in test.tb file(already  did gem install for selenium-webdriver and rspec) as shown in below screenshot.
- Right clicked on test.rb and selected Run 'test'.

Got the below output as shown in below screenshot. As a newbie I dont see any issue with the code. But its not even launching Firefox browser and not printing puts in the console.

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: you're launching it as a Ruby script. Does it work the way you need it in case you do it manually from the command line?

Comment: No Olivia! I tried to run it from project root from command line.. No luck!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're doing it wrong.

1. In your project root folder, add `Gemfile` file, this Gemfile can have something like this:

   ```rb
   source 'https://rubygems.org'
   git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

   ruby '2.6.5'

   gem 'rspec', '~> 3.9'
   gem 'capybara', '~> 3.30'
   gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.142', '>= 3.142.6'
   ```
2. Create a `spec/` directory in your project root
3. Create a `log/` directory in your project root for your selinium logs.
4. Create a `spec/spec_helper.rb` file with configuration like this:

   ```rb
   # frozen-string-literal: true

   require 'rspec'
   require 'capybara/rspec'
   require 'capybara/dsl'
   require 'selenium-webdriver'

   Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug
   Selenium::WebDriver.logger.output = File.dirname(Dir.pwd) + '/project_dir_name/log/selenium.log'

   Capybara.register_driver :firefox do |app|
     Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox)
   end

   Capybara.default_driver = :firefox
   Capybara.javascript_driver = :firefox
   Capybara.app_host = 'http://127.0.0.1:3005'
   Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10

   RSpec.configure do |config|
     config.before(:each) do
       config.include Capybara::DSL
     end
   end
   ```
5. The above code will setup rspec, capybara. You can change the driver, host and other configs if you want.
6. Now create a new `spec/features/test.rb` file with something like this:

   ```rb
   require 'spec_helper'

   describe 'Google homepage test', js: true do
     before(:each) do
       visit('https://google.com')
     end

     describe "First test" do
       it "check title" do
         expect(page.title).to be == "some text"
       end
     end
   end
   ```
7. Then run: `bundle exec rspec spec/features/test.rb` from your project root.

---

If you don't want this way, then the problem is that you're running `ruby test.rb`, actually `test.rb` this should be runned via `rspec`:

```sh
$ rspec test.rb
```

If you're using bundler, then:

```sh
$ bundle exec rspec test.rb
```

Comment: Is it necessary to do all the above steps? Because I was referring this video in YouTube => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ny2Mdl5uE9Q  (just try to watch it between 3.15 mins to 4.00 mins). He is not doing all the above steps. Am very curious to know!!  Really appreciate your reply. :)

Comment: That tutorial is very old. It's better to use Capybara. Anyways that all the above is not necessary, I've just shown how it can be done better. I've updated the answer on how to run the script.